# SharePoint Online: List column filter not showing all values present in it

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, column

A simple SharePoint custom list in office 365 has 8 columns and no special settings are enabled on it. The columns are of type choice and has 5-6 types of values present in them. The OOTB column filtering does not show all the values instead show 2-3. Can anyone help me in resolving this issue.

Example:

### Column 1

A
B
C
D
E

Showing when filter drop down is selected

### Column 1

B
C

Tried changing the type of the columns and recreating the list by saving it as a template. Both of the methods did not solve the issue.

Comment: How many items are in the list?

Comment: There are only 38 items in the list @ghangas

Comment: That's not the problem then.

Comment: Yes it's not the item threshold problem. @ghangas

Answer (score 2):

The item filtering option will display only those values of choice field which are filled up in items. If the value from choice field is not displayed under filter it indicates that it's not being used by any item.

Comment: The values are filled in the items and yet doesn't show.

Comment: Did the issue happen in classic or modern view of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the masterpage being customized to hide 'sharing' options in a team site. The UI element which is used for sharing is updated by Microsoft with the environment being SharePoint Online and it affected the list filtering capability.